# Arduino IDE v1.4.0 での gnssfw バージョン不一致？

Tags: spresense

ボードマネジャーで最新(v1.4.0)に更新し、あわせてブートローダ(FW?)も更新しました。
スケッチを書き込むとシリアルポートに以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
cxd56_farapiinitialize: Mismatched version: loader(17594) != Self(17660)
cxd56_farapiinitialize: Please update loader and gnssfw firmwares!!
```

最新のloader(17660?)はどこで入手できますでしょうか？

**環境**

- OS: Windows10 64bit
- Arduino IDE: 1.8.10

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答が付かないようなのでとりあえずコメントします。もし可能なら、どのようなスケッチなのかを公開していただけると具体性が増して回答しやすくなると思われます。スケッチ自体が最新のFWに対応していない可能性があります。

Comment: すみません。自己解決しました。
どうもbootloaderの書き込みがうまくできていなかったようで、再度書き込んだらうまく行きました。
お騒がせしました。

Comment: 問題解決されたようで安心しました。他に特に何もなければ質問のほうクローズお願いします。